# Defining symbolic expectation function

Tags: probability-or-statistics

I want to define the standard expectation $E$ operator in Mathematica. In particular, I want it to satisfy,

$E[ c + a \cdot X_1^{n_1} X_2^{n_2}  X_3^{n_3} X_4^{n_4} + b \cdot Y_1^{m_1} Y_2^{m_2} Y_3^{m_3} Y_4^{m_4} ] = 
c + a \cdot E[ X_1^{n_1} X_2^{n_2}  X_3^{n_3}  X_4^{n_4}] + b \cdot E[ Y_1^{m_1} Y_2^{m_2} Y_3^{m_3}  Y_4^{m_4} ]$

$c, a, b$ are deterministic constants, and where $n_i$ and $m_j$ are positive integers and, in particular, can take on the value $0$. I do not want to enforce a particular distribution function on these random variables. (It's even better if the code can incorporate arbitrary number of products and powers of the random variables).

In *Mathematica*, I will associate the random variables $X_i, Y_j$ as functions, say, of the form `randX[i], randY[j]`, so any value that does not match the `randX[i]` and `randY[j]` form will be regarded as deterministic constants. And the resulting moments should look like, in *Mathematica*,

```
expect[c + a * randX[1]^n1 * randX[2]^n2 * randX[3]^n3 * randX[4]^n4 + 
  b * randY[1]^m1 * randY[2]^m2 * randY[3]^m3 * randY[4]^m4]
```

> ```
> c + a * expect[randX[1]^n1 * randX[2]^n2 * randX[3]^n3 * randX[4]^n4] + 
>   b * expect[randY[1]^m1 * randY[2]^m2 * randY[3]^m3 * randY[4]^m4]
> ```

The difficulty I'm having is that I find it hard to write patterns and rules that take on the zero-value powers of those random variables.

Comment: Does the issue of $n_i = 0$ or $m_i = 0$ actually result in something that you would need to handle differently?  Do those instances get changed to 1 such that by the time that the `expect` function would operate, `randX[1]^5 * randX[2]^0 * randX[3]^4` would be changed to `randX[1]^5 * randX[3]^4` ?

Comment: @JimBaldwin No, not in particular.

Comment: Not sure if your response is for my first question or the second question.  Maybe if you showed what rules you've constructed so far (and even the ones that don't do what you want them to do), that would be helpful.

Comment: @JimBaldwin Thanks for the suggestions! I'm currently now working off of solution of Jens (see below) at the moment. In particular, I'm following the usual rules of algebra that $X_1^5 X_2^0 X_3^4 = X_1^5 X_3^4$.

Comment: Good.  At point you'll need to convert things like `expect[randX[1]^2]` to the associated moments of the random variables that you're considering.  This example (assuming that the moments exist) would result in $\sigma^2+\mu^2$ (if $\sigma^2$ is the variance of `randX[1]` and $\mu$ is the mean of `randX[1]`.  Do you have a convention for naming the moments of X[i] and Y[i] and the expectations of their products?

Comment: @JimBaldwin Thanks again. I understand the convention to convert the second and third moments say to their means $\mu$ and variances $\sigma^2$, but in the application that I have in mind, I'll be working with various higher order cross moments. And thus, it is actually rather unnatural and inconvenient to convert something like $E[ X_1^2 X_2^3 ]$ to an expression involving "lower moments". Hence, keeping it simply like $E[ X_1^2 X_2^3]$ will suffice.

Comment: I'm trying to understand your "final objective" and the "scope".  It sounds like $X_1$ and $X_2$ are not necessarily independent of each other nor do they necessarily have the same marginal distributions.  If they do have the same marginal distributions, then certainly more simplification is possible.

Comment: I simply want a way to implement the linearity of the expectation operator (assuming that all moments exist) without imposing any distributional assumption of $X_i$ and/or $Y_j$, and not imposing independence either.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here is one way of defining the linearity of your expectation value.

**Updated in response to comments**

To allow for powers as they arise in the definition of the variance, I just added rules that expand such powers when possible (it is only possible when there is a sum under the power, that's why I restrict the pattern `expect[Power[expr_Plus, n_]]` to expressions `expr` with head `Plus`), and recognize any complete expectation value `expect[...]` as a constant that can be pulled out from under a surrounding `expect`. In the treatment of `Power`, the case `n == 1` is also matched (because `Power` has a definition for a [`Default`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Default.html) second argument set equal to `1`).

```
Clear[expect]

expect[expr_Plus] := Map[expect, expr]

expect[Times[x_, y__]] /; (FreeQ[x, randX[_] | randY[_]]) := 
 x expect[Times[y]]

expect[Times[x_expect, y__]] := x expect[Times[y]]

expect[expr_?(FreeQ[#, randX[_] | randY[_]] &)] := expr

expect[Power[expr_Plus, n_]] := expect[Expand[Power[expr, n]]]

expect[Power[x_expect, n_]] := x^n

expect[
 c + a*randX[1]^n1*randX[2]^n2*randX[3]^n3*randX[4]^n4 + 
  b*randY[1]^m1*randY[2]^m2*randY[3]^m3*randY[4]^m4]
```

[image: out]

There is nothing special that needs to be done for powers of `0`. Powers of `0` make the random variable disappear, so that case is covered. In deciding whether to pull out constants, I use a [`PatternTest`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/PatternTest.html) of the form `expr_?(...)` check that the random variables don't appear in `expr` (unless wrapped by `expect`, which when raised to any power counts as a constant, too - that's the last definition).

With the rules for `Power` and `Times` involving `expect` itself, we also get the desired simplification of the variance:

```
expect[(randX[1] - expect[randX[1]])^2]
```

> `-expect[randX[1]]^2 + expect[randX[1]^2]`

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Is it possible to expand your solution? In particular, there are often cases when one needs to consider, say $Z := c + a X_1^{n_1} X_2^{n_2} X_3^{n_3} X_4^{n_4} $ and consider the computation $E[ (Z - E[Z])^2 ] $ (i.e. the variance of $Z$); and likewise, consider the other central moments of $Z$. In this case, your current code would generate something like expect[ expect[randZ] ] and does not pull out the deterministic expect[randZ] inside. Thanks (in particular, since I'm a novice to Mathematica)!

Comment: What @Jens gave you will do the job if you use the `Expand` function.  `z = c + a*randX[1]^n1*randX[2]^n2*randX[3]^n3*randX[4]^n4;
Simplify[expect[Expand[z^2]] - Expand[expect[z]^2]]` results in `a^2 (-expect[randX[1]^n1 randX[2]^n2 randX[3]^n3 randX[4]^n4]^2 + 
   expect[randX[1]^(2 n1) randX[2]^(2 n2) randX[3]^(2 n3) randX[4]^(
     2 n4)])`.

Comment: Thanks again! This does indeed work --- however, it seems to require the user to know the algebraic identity that $Var(Z) := E[ (Z - E[Z])^2 ] = E[Z^2] - ( E Z )^2$, which is fine for the variance. But I'm not sure how does one think about using Expand when one considers say, the 3rd centralized moment (for skewness) $ E[ (Z - E[Z])^3 ] $, as expanding that would still involve a computation of a term like $ E [ E[Z] Z ] $ and the code Jens currently has doesn't allow for the computation $ E [ E[Z] Z ] = E[Z] E[Z] = ( E[Z] )^2 $. Same comment applies for other higher centralized moments.

Comment: Might this work:  `Expand[expect[Expand[(z - ez)^3]] /. ez -> expect[z]]`.  And, of course, instead of 3 one could put in any positive integer.

Answer (score 5):

I recently ran into this same question and came up with a slightly more convenient solution based on Jens answer that I think is different enough to be worth sharing. First I define two functions, `RandomVariableQ` and `MakeRandomVariable`

```
(*atoms are not RVs unless explicitly marked*) 
RandomVariableQ[expr_?AtomQ] := False

(*recurse down expression tree until we reach an atom or expectation value*)
RandomVariableQ[expr_ /; (!AtomQ[expr]) && (Head[expr] =!= AngleBracket)] := Or @@ Map[RandomVariableQ,List @@ expr]

(*expectation values are not RVs*)
RandomVariableQ[expr__AngleBracket] := False

(*make a symbol into a RV*)
MakeRandomVariable[x__Symbol] := (# /: RandomVariableQ[#] := True;) & /@ List[x]
```

`MakeRandomVariable` can be used to mark a particular symbol as being a random variable that cannot be factored out of an expectation. `RandomVariableQ` returns true if an expression contains a random variable that is not wrapped in an expectation value.

I then define `AngleBracket` as the expectation value

```
(*Linear*)
AngleBracket[expr_Plus] := AngleBracket /@ expr
AngleBracket[Times[x_, y__]] /; !RandomVariableQ[x] := x AngleBracket[Times[y]]

(*Expectation values only operate on RVs*)
AngleBracket[expr_ /; !RandomVariableQ[expr]] := expr

(*Expand before taking expectation values*)
AngleBracket[Power[expr_Plus, n_]] := AngleBracket[Expand[Power[expr, n]]]
AngleBracket[Times[expr_Plus, x_?RandomVariableQ]] := AngleBracket[Expand[expr x]]
```

Note here I am using `RandomVariableQ` instead of `FreeQ`. This allows the code to correctly recognize that arbitrary functions of expectation values can be factored out of an expectation value, i.e $\left\langle f(\left\langle x \right\rangle) \right \rangle = f(\left\langle x \right\rangle)$

We can test the code by computing the first 5 central moments of a random variable

```
MakeRandomVariable[x];
Table[AngleBracket[(x - AngleBracket[x])^n], {n, 2, 5}] // TableForm
```

which produces

$$
\begin{array}{c}
 \left\langle x^2\right\rangle -\langle x\rangle ^2 \\
 \left\langle x^3\right\rangle -3 \left\langle x^2\right\rangle  \langle x\rangle +2 \langle x\rangle ^3 \\
 \left\langle x^4\right\rangle -4 \left\langle x^3\right\rangle  \langle x\rangle +6 \left\langle x^2\right\rangle  \langle x\rangle
   ^2-3 \langle x\rangle ^4 \\
 \left\langle x^5\right\rangle -5 \left\langle x^4\right\rangle  \langle x\rangle +10 \left\langle x^3\right\rangle  \langle x\rangle
   ^2-10 \left\langle x^2\right\rangle  \langle x\rangle ^3+4 \langle x\rangle ^5 \\
\end{array}
$$

as desired. This is an improvement on the current solution which cannot simplify expressions such as `expect[expect[randX[1]]^2 randX[1]]` because it does not recognize that expect[randX[1]]^2 can be pulled out of the expectation value. This also works as expected with multiple random variables.