# Efficient way to apply linear function to multivariate polynomial

Tags: probability-or-statistics, polynomials

Suppose I start with an expression that is a multivariate polynomial in $x_k$'s,
$$W = a + b \cdot x_1^{n_1} x_2^{n_2} x_3^{n_3} x_4^{n_4} + c \cdot x_1^{m_1} x_2^{m_2} x_3^{m_3} x_4^{m_4}$$

where $a, b, c$ are just constants, and $n_i, m_j$ are nonnegative integers, and $x_k$'s are real scalars.

Now, suppose I apply a linear operator $L$ (what I have in mind is the expectation operator from probability and statistics) to the above, and associate 
$$L[ x_1^{n_1} x_2^{n_2} x_3^{n_3} x_4^{n_4} ] = M( n_1, n_2, n_3, n_4)$$

(i.e. in probability and statistics, $M$ would correspond to the moment $E[X_1^{n_1} X_2^{n_2} X_3^{n_3} X_4^{n_4}]$), so that 
$$L[W] = a + b \cdot L[x_1^{n_1} x_2^{n_2} x_3^{n_3} x_4^{n_4}] + c \cdot L[x_1^{m_1} x_2^{m_2} x_3^{m_3} x_4^{m_4}] \\= a + b M(n_1, n_2, n_3, n_4) + c M(m_1, m_2, m_3, m_4)$$,

and suppose that the function $M$ can be computed numerically quickly. The objective is to compute $L[W]$ efficiently.

**Question:** Wow does one do this efficiently when there are many, many terms in the polynomial?

That is, suppose

```
w = a + b * x1^n1 * x2^n2 * x3^n3 * x4^n4 + c * x1^m1 * x2^m2 * x3^m3 * x4^m4
```

The current method that I have is effectively to use `CoefficientRules` applied to $W$, and say get `wcr = CoefficientRules[w]`, and then compute `Keys[wcr]`, which will then get me a list of the exponents associated with $x_k$'s. Apply my function $M$, say `mlist = mfun @@@ Keys[wcr]`. And then finally, to put everything back together, I will then simply multiply, and get `resultL = Values[wcr] * mlist` (I could also use `Dot`, I suppose). But in the application I have in my mind, I have potentially hundreds and thousands of terms, so I figured out that the multiplication step is taking considerable amount of time.

Comment: Instead of explaining your code in words, it would be beneficial if you were to insert it into your question verbatim (and properly formatted). I, for one, am too obtuse to follow your MathJaX notation.

Comment: Is there a finite number of possible monomials in your polynomials? For instance, is there an upper bound on the exponents?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One obvious answer is to use the answer to your [related earlier question](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/91700/245) with the straightforward modification of renaming the random variables:

```
Clear[expect]

expect[expr_Plus] := Map[expect, expr]

expect[Times[x_, y__]] /; (FreeQ[x, x1 | x2 | x3 | x4]) := 
 x expect[Times[y]]

expect[Times[x_expect, y__]] := x expect[Times[y]]

expect[expr_?(FreeQ[#, x1 | x2 | x3 | x4] &)] := expr

expect[Power[expr_Plus, n_]] := expect[Expand[Power[expr, n]]]

expect[Power[x_expect, n_]] := x^n
```

The apply it as follows:

```
w = a + b*x1^n1*x2^n2*x3^n3*x4^n4 + c*x1^m1*x2^m2*x3^m3*x4^m4

expect[w]

(*
==> a + c expect[x1^m1 x2^m2 x3^m3 x4^m4] + 
 b expect[x1^n1 x2^n2 x3^n3 x4^n4]
*)
```

Now you just have to add a definition for the expectation value of the monomials as follows:

```
expect[x_] := M[x]

expect[w]

(*
==> a + c M[x1^m1 x2^m2 x3^m3 x4^m4] + 
 b M[x1^n1 x2^n2 x3^n3 x4^n4]
*)
```

Here, I assume the fast implementation of the expectation value you mention in the question is called `M`. By omitting any restrictions on the pattern in `expect[w_]`, this definition is the last one that kicks in, after the linearity properties have already been applied.

Comment: Thanks again for the response. It turns out that my computational bottleneck is actually not at this step, but in the implementation of the function `M` that I had hinted at (which I'd originally thought was fast, but upon some checking, had some errors). I do gratefully accept your answer since it does answer my initial question.