# Transformation rule for arbitrary number of argument expressions

Tags: pattern-matching, replacement

I am failing to write a *Mathematica* transformation rule that replaces e.g. `f[a + 3, b + 3, c + 3]` with `f[a, b, c] + 3` for an arbitrary number of arguments. However, `f[a + 3, b + 3, c + 2]` should remain untouched after the transformation.

Comment: `f[a + 3, b + 3, c + 3] /. f[pat : (_ + n_) ..] :> f @@ ({pat} - n) + n`. Would you be willing to show what you've tried so that we can get a handle on where you're at, *Mathematica*-knowledge-wise?

Comment: related: [91700](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/91700/5478)

Comment: In addition, can you expand on your problem? It's not specified enough, and so it's quite possible that people will spend time figuring out how to answer your question, and then you'll show a different example on which it fails. Or maybe it'll be a case where you want to specify what number (e.g. 3) gets pulled out. Please include more information in your post, and then I will consider posting an answer.

Comment: @march Your proposed replacement doesn't seem to work for me. Could you check it?

Comment: @MarcoB. I copied and pasted from my comment, and it worked for me! Are you trying it with some other input?

Comment: @march That's weird. Here's what I see: [image](http://i.stack.imgur.com/h5iAk.png). I'm on MMA 10.4.0 / Win7-64.

Comment: @MarcoB. Yep that's weird. I have 10.0.1 on Mac OSX 10.10.5. [Here's what I get.](http://i.stack.imgur.com/0tgqD.png) Does adding lots of parentheses in various places fix the problem? Maybe this? `f[a + 3, b + 3, c + 3] /. 
 f[pat : ((_ + n_) ..)] :> n + f @@ ({pat} - n)`

Comment: @march That's rather bizarre. Gotta go to lunch now, but I'll play with it a bit more later.

Comment: I cannot see why march's code *should not* work, yet on my system also (10.1.0 under Windows 7 x64) it does not.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your replies. I experience the same problem with march's code. However, it works if I modify to to `a + 3, b + 3, c + 3] /. 
 f[pat : (n_Integer + _) ..] :> f @@ ({pat} - n) + n`.

Comment: @Mr.Wizard and rest, isn't it a reordering somewhere what causes that? `_+n_` stays the same while `a+3` is `3+a` so repeated element is the first one, not the second like in pattern. This works well `MatchQ[ f[a + 3, b + 3, c + 3], f[Verbatim[Plus][n_, _] ..] ]` but I don't know how OS affects that.

Comment: @Kuba I thought the `Orderless` attribute of `Plus` would handle that but I guess not.  I really should know this stuff better. :-/  I confirm your `MatchQ` is true.

Comment: @march Here is your replacement rule compatible with Windows :P `f[p : Verbatim[Plus][___, n_, ___] ..] :> n + f @@ ({p} - n)`. Please consider posting an answer.

Comment: @Kuba I think I am forgetting my own answers: [(94432)](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/94432/121)

Comment: @Kuba Realize that by making this order-dependent your replacement will not work on `f[1 + x, 2 + x, 3 + x]` for example.

Comment: @Mr.Wizard Now I don't understand why this does not match ... `f[Verbatim[Plus][___, n_, ___] ..]`

Comment: @Kuba Me neither. I feel like I have been [nerd sniped](https://xkcd.com/356/). :^)

Comment: @Kuba Mr.Wizard: Perhaps I will avoid posting an answer until this is somewhat cleared up. However, does a function deconstruction version work or does it suffer from the same problem? `f[pat : (_ + n_) ..] := f @@ ({pat} - n) + n; f[a + 3, b + 3, c + 3]`. You could probably do something like `SetAttributes[f, HoldFirst]` to make it work...

Comment: @Mr.Wizard. I tried my code in V8 on a Windows machine, and it still worked :/

Comment: @march The code from your original comment also works as written in version 7.0.1 under Windows.  Something has changed and we need to know what and why.  Do you care to post a question about this?  I expect it is going to end up popular and I think you deserve the credit for bringing it to our attention, even if unintentionally.

Comment: @Mr.Wizard. Will do. Feel free to edit it once it's up, since I'm not precisely sure how to ask the question. We'll see how it goes.

Comment: @Mr.Wizard. Also, since I can't check which things *don't* work (they all work for me on all of my machines and in all of the versions I have access to), I can only use the examples listed in this thread. That will have to do!

Comment: @Mr.Wizard. I have posted the question [here](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/121564/what-has-changed-in-pattern-matching-functions-with-the-orderless-attribute). Feel free to edit (including the title, since I'm not sure that it's the `Orderless` attribute that is the problem).

Answer (score 5):

Since the problem is specified without context, here is a very specific solution:

```
expr = f[a + 3, b + 3, c + 3, d + 3, e + 3];

Thread[expr, Plus] /. f[n_ ..] :> n
```

> ```
> 3 + f[a, b, c, d, e]
> ```

---

Leaving aside the curious question of pattern matching raised in the comments here is a baroque approach that should at least be applicable in a number of cases.

```
rep[a : f[__Plus]] :=
  With[
    {out = Plus @@ f @@@ Factor[Plus @@ Times @@@ (a /. n_?NumericQ :> Hold[n])]},
    (out /. {Hold[n_] :> n, f[x_] :> x}) /; Length[out] == 2
  ]
```

Test:

```
f[a + 3, b + 3, c + 3, 3 + d] // rep
f[1 + x, 2 + x, 3 + x]        // rep
f[1 + x, 2 + x, x + y]        // rep
```

> ```
> 3 + f[a, b, c, d]
>
> x + f[1, 2, 3]
>
> x + f[y, 1, 2]
> ```

There must be a better way but I am too distracted by the patten matching issue to refine this now.

Comment: Thanks! It works great for the question I posed. I added a second example to clarify what I had initially omitted to explain.

Answer (score 4):

Maybe this will fit your needs

```
ReplaceAll[
 { 
  f[a + 3, b + 3, c + 3], 
  f[x + 3, x + 3, x + 1], 
  f[x + 2, y + 3, x + 1]
 },
 f[p__] :> With[{c = Intersection[p]}, c + f @@ ({p} - c)]
    (*thanks to J.M.*)
 ]
]
```

> ```
> {
>    3 + f[a, b, c], 
>    x + f[3, 3, 1], 
>    f[2 + x, 3 + y, 1 + x] 
> }
> ```

Earlier I overdid it with `f[p__] :> With[{c = Plus @@ Intersection @@ (List @@@ {p})}, f @@ (# - c & /@ {p}) + c`

Comment: ...or, `f[p__] :> With[{c = Intersection[p]}, c + f @@ ({p} - c)]`.

Comment: @J.M. That is indeed better. I have overdid it because of some `f` values hanging around and messing with my code :)

Comment: @J.M. I used your example, if that is not a problem :)

Comment: I'm happy you did.

Answer (score 0):

With a typed pattern.

```
ClearAll[Evaluate[Context[] <> "*"]];
k = 1;
ReplaceAll[
 {f[a + 1, b + 1, k + c], g[x - π, y - π, -π + z], h[u + 1, v + 2, w + 3]},
 f_[p : ((_Symbol + n_?NumericQ) ..)] :> n + f[Sequence @@ Cases[{p}, _Symbol, 2]]
 ]

(* {1 + f[a, b, c], -π + g[x, y, z], h[1 + u, 2 + v, 3 + w]} *)
```

Hope this helps.