# Orderless breaks pattern match

Tags: bugs, pattern-matching

**Bug introduced in 10.3 or earlier and persisting through 12.0.0**

 10.0.2 is not affected.

---

I am perplexed by the effect of `Orderless` on pattern matching. Starting from a clean Kernel (i.e. after using Quit), I find the following expected match for function `g` without any definitions or attributes

```
MatchQ[g[a[1], b[1]], g[(Y : (a | b))[i__], b[1]]]
(* True *)
```

If I do the same for a symbol `f` with `Attributes[f] = {Orderless}`

```
Attributes[f] = {Orderless};
MatchQ[f[a[1], b[1]], f[(Y : (a | b))[i__], b[1]]]
(* False *)
```

it returns `False`. I would have expected `True`.  If I replace `i__` with `1` on the RHS I get `True` again.

```
MatchQ[f[a[1], b[1]], f[(Y : (a | b))[1], b[1]]]
(* True *)
```

The same goes for

```
MatchQ[f[a[1], b[1]], f[(Y : (a | c))[i__]]
```

So the issue does not seem to be that  `b` somehow gets matched on the wrong side. Also Orderless seems to prefer the same (flipped) order regardless of whether I change `i__` to `1`. (And this should be irrelevant anyway since `f` has orderless.

What am I missing here?

Comment: `Orderless` sorts the symbols. Have a look at `OrderlessPatternSequence`. E.g., `MatchQ[f[a[1], b[1]], 
 f[OrderlessPatternSequence[(Y : (a | b))[i__], b[1]]]]` might do what you want.

Comment: @HenrikSchumacher, thanks. I seem to have been completely mistaken about what Orderless does then. I understand it would sort the result, but for pattern matching it should try all orders again right? So making the order unimportant. "In matching patterns with Orderless functions, all possible orders of arguments are tried." Now it seems that each time I use a pattern on a orderless symbol I will need to use OrderlessPatternSequence myself. How should I understand the documentation if it does not really mean that all orders will be tried for pattern matching.

Comment: "How should I understand the documentation...?" Well, that's a question for which I don't have any answer. Maybe I am also mistaken, things should work as you expected, and there is some other issue that I don't see at the moment. Let's wait for further opinion.

Comment: `MatchQ[f[a[1],b[1]],_[(Y:(a|b))[i__],b[1]]]`->`True`, 
`MatchQ[f[a[1],b[1]],_[b[1],(Y:(a|b))[i__]]]`->`False`, 
`MatchQ[f[b[1],a[1]],_[(Y:(a|b))[i__],b[1]]]`->`True`, 
`MatchQ[f[b[1],a[1]],_[b[1],(Y:(a|b))[i__]]]`->`False`.

When pattern is any head it seems to only match the pattern which is canonical order of parts, probably because `f[b[1],a[1]]` has canonical form `f[a[1],b[1]]`.

Comment: Also gives `True` if `BlankSequence[]` (the double underbar) is changed to `Blank[]`. I do not know why one matches and the other does not.

Comment: Looks like a bug to me.  Even a simpler example fails: `MatchQ[f[a[], b[]], f[_[___], b[]]]` returns false yet `MatchQ[f[a[], b[]], f[_[], b[]]]` returns true.

Comment: Reported as a bug.

Comment: @DanielLichtblau. Is this related to [this problem](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/121564/what-has-changed-in-pattern-matching-functions-with-the-orderless-attribute?noredirect=1&lq=1) (that appears to be fixed)?

Comment: @march As best I can tell they are different issues.

Comment: When there is a bug, please include an easy-to-test example in the post. This way people can quickly check which versions are affected.